# What package do I use to replace dkim-filter?

Tags: 11.10, package-management, postfix

It looks like dkim-filter is no longer in the repositories as of Natty... what package should I install if I want to add dkim support to postfix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sudo apt-get install opendkim

opendkim is a fork from dkim-milter. Maybe that's what you meant by dkim-filter?

Comment: thanks, I'm using opendkim now; but no, the ubuntu package is called dkim-filter, and still exists for Lucid: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/dkim-filter/